# Why are git commits on a merged branch showing on my main branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch

I currently have a git commit tree that looks something like this with pointers (?) in parentheses:

```
*   305f Merge branch 'develop' (HEAD->master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|\
| * d97b Some other commit on dev branch (develop) 
| * df14 Some commit on dev branch
|/
* 7a761b6 Initial commit
```

I've pushed master branch to remote (Gitlab, if it matters), and when I look at the commits on the master branch in the Gitlab UI, all 4 commits are present, where I would have expected only the "Merge branch 'develop'" and "Initial commit" commits to be present on the master branch.

My understanding is that `master` refers to the two commits I just listed, whereas `develop` refers to "Some other..." , "Some commit...", and possibly "Initial commit" as well, since it is an ancestor.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The merge operation is what makes commits `d97b` and `df14` to be reachable from `master`. What did you expect merging `develop` into `master` would achieve, if not this?

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks for the answer! I guess I expected the behavior of master having those commits, but I thought that master's list of commits would just say "Merge branch 'develop'" to imply all the commits that that entails, keeping the master branch itself clean. I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), and was expecting master to only show the commits in light blue. So just to clarify, even in that tutorial, `master` actually refers to every single commit, in all of the branches, that have ended up in master?

Comment: A branch is a pointer to *one* commit. When we say that "this commit is on that branch", we mean that said commit is, starting from the tip commit (most recent) of that branch and going backwards in history, *reachable* by ancestry.

Comment: I think you could see things like that: Gitlab Ui shows you all the commits that "contribute" at how the source code is in `master` workspace.

Comment: @RomainValeri and @ Philippe, that makes sense, thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some version control systems, when you make commit *C* on branch *B*, commit *C* is on branch *B* forever.  Anyone who obtains commit *C* acquires branch *B*.  If they had *their own* branch *B* before, well, now *their* branch *B* has a new commit *C* in it.

Git *does not* do this.  Commits are not permanently tacked to branches.  However, commits *are* mostly permanent,<sup>1</sup> and permanently tacked to where they appear in the *commit graph*.  In order to make this work, commits aren't really made on *any* branches.  Instead, a branch name is merely a label.  Multiple labels can all point to the *same commit*, as in:

> ```
> *   305f Merge branch 'develop' (HEAD->master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
> ```

Here `master` and `origin/master`<sup>2</sup> both identify commit `305f`.  If you create a new branch `br2` now, that name will *also* point to commit `305f`.

Commit `305f` has *two* parents: `7a761b6` (its first parent) and `d97b` (its second parent).  The full name of `305f` is whatever its full hash ID is.  This will never change; and that hash ID is forever reserved for *that* commit, which will always have the same two parents.  That commit is frozen for all time and will never move.

The things in Git that *do* move are the *branch names*.  Currently, `master` means `305f`.  A moment ago, however, `master` meant `7a761b6`.  Commits stay in place, forever, as found by their raw hash IDs.  Branch names move about.

The result of all of this is that the set of branches that contain some commit changes, dynamically, as we create and destroy branch names.  At this time, the name `master` lets you find all four commits.  If you allow Git to move the name `master` in the ways that Git prefers, those four commits will continue to be reachable, by starting at `305f` and viewing both of its parents, then viewing the parent of `d97b` (and then from `d97b` you get back to `7a761b6` which you already saw).  Note that *new* commits only ever *add to the graph*.  In general, each new commit will have some existing commit as its parent—its only parent if it's a typical commit, or one of two parents if it's a merge commit.<sup>3</sup>

If we draw these things sideways, it's a little easier.  To make it even easier than that, we can use single uppercase letters to stand in for the incomprehensible hash IDs that Git uses:

```
        D--E   <-- br1
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G   <-- br2
```

Here, the name `br1` allows us to find commit `E`, which finds `D`, then `C`, then `B`, then `A` (and stops because `A` is the first commit).  The name `br2` allows us to find `G`, then `F`, then `C`, then `B`, then `A` (and then stop).  So the first three commits are on *both* branches, while two commits are each only one one branch.

Erasing the *name* `br1` causes commits `D` and `E` to become unfindable.  Eventually Git will throw them out for real.  If we instead add a new commit by doing `git checkout br1`, make whatever changes we want, `git add`, and `git commit`, we get a new hash ID `H` and advance the name `br1` to include it:

```
        D--E--H   <-- br1
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G   <-- br2
```

Now there are six commits reachable from `br1`, starting with `H` and working backwards.  If we make a new name `br3` to remember where `E` is, we'll want to redraw the graph a bit:

```
             H   <-- br2
            /
        D--E   <-- br3
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G   <-- br2
```

Note that none of the *commits* have actually changed: we just shoved `H` up to make room for the label `br3`.

If we remove the *name* `br3` later, that's OK: there are no commits that are *exlusively* found through `br3`.  Commit `E` won't go away because `br1` finds `H` which finds `E`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *mostly* comes about through *reachability*.  You *find* commits by starting from some branch or tag name, which supplies a raw hash ID.  Then, having found a commit, you use its parent hash ID(s) to find its predecessor commit(s).  Then you use *those* commits to find *their* parents, and so on.

By doing this process from *every* reference—see footnote 2—Git finds all *reachable* commits.  Any commits that exist in the repository, that are not reaachable by this process, eventually get garbage-collected and removed.

<sup>2</sup>The name `master` is a branch name.  Its full name is really `refs/heads/master`, and names whose full name starts with `refs/heads/` are branch names.  By contrast, `origin/master` is actually a *remote-tracking* name: its full name starts with `refs/remotes/` and then goes on to say `origin/master`.  Git sometimes strips only the `refs/` part from this name, so that you see `remotes/origin/master`.

Tags, if you have any, live in `refs/tags/`.  These things are collectively called *refs* or *references*.  There are additional, hidden references kept in *reflogs*.  A reflog is simply a log file keeping the values—the previous hash IDs—that were stored in a ref before you, or Git, updated it.  These reflog entries eventually expire, which is how deliberately-abandoned commits—those you've replaced with new-and-improved versions that have new hash IDs, for instance—are eventually cleaned out.

<sup>3</sup>The technical definition of a *merge commit* is that it is one with at least two parents.  You can therefore create a merge commit with 3 or more parents, too—but there's rarely a reason to do that.  I should also mention that it's possible to create a new commit with *no* parent.  Except for the very first commit—the one I label `A` in the sideways graph drawings—you won't do that in normal practice either.